# javascript looping alphabet with a SEARCHTERM

Tags: javascript, loops

I am having a problem. I am trying to loop an input value that goes to a $.getJSON, here is an example:

user submits SERCHTERM,

I need it to be looped with the alphabet, such as:

```
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM a
SEARCHTERM a
SEARCHTERM a
a SEARCHTERM
a SEARCHTERM
a SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM b
SEARCHTERM b
SEARCHTERM b
b SEARCHTERM
b SEARCHTERM
b SEARCHTERM
```

How would I go about doing this?

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
_.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
callAPI(search_input + ' ' + letter);
});
```

My site: http://Keyworda.com (I will be using the code here)

Relevant Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp
    var keywordCount = 0;
    $('body').on("click", '#submit', function() {
        $('#keywords').html('');
        var search_input = $("#keyword").val();
        var language = $("#edit-domain").val();
        callAPI(search_input, language);
        var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
        _.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
        callAPI(letter + ' ' + search_input); // add this line
        callAPI(search_input + ' ' + letter);
        });
        return false;
    });

    function callAPI(search_input, language){

          $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?", {
            "hl": language, // Language
            //"ds":"yt", // Restrict lookup to youtube
            "jsonp": "suggestCallBack", // jsonp callback function name
            "q": search_input, // query term
            "client": "youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
        });
        suggestCallBack = function(data) {
            var suggestions = [];
            var languageText = $("#edit-domain option:selected").text();
            $('#keywordTable').show();
            $.each(data[1], function(key, val) {
                suggestions.push({
                    "value": val[0]
                });
                $('#keywordTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + search_input + '</td><td>' + val[0] + '</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>');
                $('#keywordCount').text(++keywordCount);
                $('#keywordtext').text(search_input);
                $('#languageholder').text(languageText);
            });
        }

        }

</script>
```

Comment: what is the result of what you are trying here?

Comment: why do you have every line 3 times?

Comment: Here is the result:  http://i.imgur.com/zgAtB3E.png, code; http://i.imgur.com/HxwAogw.png , but the searchterm seems to be showing the last result for all for some reason

Comment: it should really be 10 times instead of 3, because google shows 10 suggestions per keyword.

Comment: Can you try to show the expected result? I really don't understand

Comment: If you do a search on www.keyworda.com, it will show the correct keywords (2nd column), but the 1st column only shows the last looped with alpha bet (SEARCHTERM 9, for ALL, instead of SEARCHTERM A, SEARCHTERM B, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `a SEARCHTERM`:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
_.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
    callAPI(letter + ' ' + search_input); // add this line
    callAPI(search_input + ' ' + letter);
});
```

Comment: this kinda works, however the "search_input" seems to only show the last result. (SEARCHTERM 9) for all instead of showing each.

Comment: How is that related to the question? You don't have search_input there, I thought it's a global variable

Comment: search_input is just a textfield entered by the user, here is the code: http://i.imgur.com/HxwAogw.png, but some reason its showing the correct keyword suggestions, but only showing the last result of search_input + letter

Comment: Please add your relevant code to the question. Not everyone can read images, and also the image (link) might disappear in the future

Comment: Isn't it because you do the same search 10 times, and the browser is caching the ajax requests to the same URL? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: search?callback=jQuery111308281447815243155_1454033551775&hl=us&jsonp=suggestCallBack&q=SEARCHTERM&client=youtube&_=1454033551791 200 script jquery.min.js:5 550 B 48 ms 
search?callback=jQuery111308281447815243155_1454033551749&jsonp=suggestCallBack&q=a+SEARCHTERM&client=youtube&_=1454033551792 200 script jquery.min.js:5 474 B 61 ms

Comment: So you have each term only once. Can you have a look at the response headers? Is it cachable?

Comment: I dont think its the cache because it somehow shows the correct suggested keyword, but not the actual searchterm used to get those keywords.